# How do I connect to a database with a blank password using a shell script?

Tags: mysql, backup

```
## connect to mysql and source backup file ##
USER="root"
PASS=""

mysql -u$USER -p$PASS database_name < backup.sql
```

Above is my shell script which I used to source database but still its asking for password. I just want to know how can I source database in case of blank password. If root password is not blank than it works fine.

Comment: An empty database password is not acceptable, ever, and and empty root password is completely unthinkable.

Comment: It is also not a good idea (especially on a shared system) to have the user+password on the command line: anyone logged into the machine can potentially read them from the task list. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-security-user.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html for the preferred alternative.

Answer (score 6):

If root has no password you could just do this:

```
mysql -u$USER database_name < backup.sql
```

If you want to code so that root can be given a password later, do this in the script

```
USER="root"
PASS=""
if [ "${PASS}" == "" ]
then
    PASSWORD=""
else
    PASSWORD="-p${PASS}"
fi
mysql -u${USER} ${PASSWORD} database_name < backup.sql
```

Give it a Try !!!

## CAVEAT

If is usually not a good idea to have root without a password. Please give it one.

Comment: I edited the code, please check.

Answer (score 4):

Use `--password` instead of `-p`:

```
mysql "--username=$USER" "--password=$PASS" < backup.sql
```

Comment: this is actually the best answer. using `--password` makes it work even with empty passwords, which is the desired behavior.

Comment: Noting this does not work anymore: `mysql "--username=root" "--password="
mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'username=root'.`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to specify server connection information is with your .mylogin.cnf file. Not only is this file encrypted, but any logging of the utility execution does not expose the connection information. Thus, no user names, passwords, ports, etc. are visible in the log. This is the preferred method for using MySQL Utilities to connect to servers.

Taken from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysql-utils-intro-connspec-mylogin.cnf.html

This removes the need from specifying your password in the command line and secure.

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=instance_13001 --host=localhost --user=root --port=13001 --password
Enter password: <Password is prompted to be inserted in a more secure way>


mysql --login-path=KeyPath....
```